# Insert element at position i and return info based on i first elements

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, data-structures

Let's say I have a list of integers:

```
2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 2
```

I want to be able to insert a new integer at position `i`. So let's say `i` is 4, and I want to insert the number 7. The result would be:

```
2, 1, 3, 7, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 2
```

After the insertion, I would like to receive some information based on numbers at positions `i` and lower. For example, the sum of the first `i` numbers. In this case it would be `2 + 1 + 3 + 7 = 13`.

I want to be able to repeat this process over and over.

I wrote a program in C++ that uses `std::list`. Here's what it does to insert `n` at position `i` into `List` and then return the sum of `i` first numbers:

1. Compare the last insert position `k` with `i`. If it's lower, calculate `sum[j]` for each `j: k < j < i` like this: `sum[j] = sum[j-1] + List[j]` *- O(n)*
2. Find position `i` *- O(n)*
3. Insert `n` at position `i`, store `k = i` *- O(1)*
4. Calculate and return `sum[i] = sum[i-1] + n` *- O(1)*

Can this be done more efficiently, perhaps using a different data structure? In *O(logn)* maybe? If yes then how?

Comment: At first glance it sounds like a job for a [Binary Indexed Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree)

Comment: The sum of `n` elements will take _O(n)_ but it will be faster when using a `std::vector<int>`. Finding the position is _O(1)_ for `std::vector<int>`. You'd trade that for inserting taking _O(n)_. On your short lists using a `std::vector<int>` will be a lot faster. On a large data set it will depend on how much you need shift but a vector is just way after in its operations.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that position 4 would actually be where the 1 is, since position in arrays starts counting at 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an out-of-the-box solution without rolling a new data structure or using a third party lib, `std::vector` would be your best bet. The algorithmic complexity would be:

1. Compare the last insert position `k` with `i`. If it's lower, calculate sum: `O(n)`
2. Find position i: `O(1)` or `O(n)` if it involves some kind of search. If there's a search involved, it will still be substantially faster than `std::list`.
3. Insert `n` at position `i`: `O(n)`
4. Calculate and return `sum[i] = sum[i-1] + n`: `O(1)`

This might not seem better from an algorithmic/scalability standpoint, yet it wouldn't be due to algorithmic complexity that we would typically see a considerable performance improvement. It'd be due to locality of reference (spatial locality in particular).

The machine can plow through contiguous data sequentially very quickly, since multiple adjacent elements can be accessed prior to being evicted from a cache line. `std::vector` has that going for it in spades, and we end up benefiting from its rapid, contiguous, sequential access for all 4 cases above.

`std::list`, when used with `std::allocator` (especially in a context where not all nodes are allocated at once), tends to invoke a lot of cache-misses since it lacks spatial locality (also, in part, due to the overhead of the list pointers which reduces the number of elements that can fit into a cache line, and in this particular case, substantially since we require two list pointers per measly integer).

Note that potentially more optimal solutions exist when venturing outside the standard library which are tuned for your specific problem, as mentioned in the other nice answer. Another angle that delves into lower-level details is to seek your own custom allocator which can really help just about any kind of linked structure. This answer focuses on vanilla C++. There `vector` is often your best bet (unless given some strong reasons otherwise) when dealing with a sequential container given its contiguous, cache-friendly representation.

Answer (score 0):

As @andyg mentioned in comments this is a job that suits Fenwick tree or Binary Indexed tree. Binary Indexed Tree can do insertion and update in `O(logn)`, and query ( sum from beginning to an index ) in `O(logn)`. There is a very good article about Binary Indexed Tree [here](https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/binary-indexed-trees/).

Also this job can be done with segment tree but as implementation of Binary Indexed Tree is so much simpler, I recommend using Binary Indexed Tree.